# Match word ending with either one of two special characters in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check if `word.` or `word:` is part of the string.

```
if (/word\b/.test(str) )
```

This is the best solution I came up with, but I'd like to match only for `word.` or `word:`.

I was trying something in the following lines, but can't get it to work:

```
if (/word\/(.|:)/i.test(str)
```

How to go about this?

Comment: `if (/word[.:]/i.test(str))` or `if (/word(\.|:)]/i.test(str))`

Answer (score 0):

You may leverage a character class `[.:]` to match either a dot or a colon, and then add a non-word boundary `\B` to make sure there is a non-word char after the dot/colon, or the end of string:

```
if (/word[.:]\B/i.test(str)
```

As an alternative, you may require a whitespace or the end of string after `.` or `:`:

```
if (/word[.:](?=\s|$)/i.test(str)
```